# Azure Rest Service to create OS disk

Tags: rest, azure

I'm trying to add a disk to a Subscription using the Add Disk REST service ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj157178.aspx )

I tried pretty much every combination explained but no matter what I do, the disk is listed as a Data Disk.
Trying use fiddler to inspect how the Azure PowerShell (https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/downloads/ ) just results in an error.
According to MS, you should specify `HasOperatingSystem` but you don’t supply it when using Microsoft’s `PScmdlet`. If you do a List Disks ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj157176 ) it should send this too, but the only way to distinct Data disks from OS disk’s is weather ”OS” is null or contains ”windows”/”Linux”. Given that information I tried creating the disk with/without OS and/or `HasOperatingSystem` in all combinations, and no matter what I always end up being a Data disk.
Using Microsoft PowerShell `CDMLets` allow using both HTTP and HTTPS in URI, so tried both of those too.

Does anyone have a **WORKING** example of the xml to send, to create an OS disk?

```
<Disk xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure">
  <HasOperatingSystem>true</HasOperatingSystem>
  <Label>d2luZ3VuYXY3MDEtbmF2NzAxLTAtMjAxMjA4MjcxNTA5NTU=</Label>
  <MediaLink>http://winguvhd.blob.core.windows.net/nav701/nav701-0-20120827150955_osdisk.vhd</MediaLink>
  <Name>wingunav701-nav701-0-20120827150955</Name>
  <OS>Windows</OS>
</Disk>
```

Comment: I tried the same and observed the same behavior as you are observing. Based on my experience with Service Management API, I believe there's an issue with the documentation. I have had so many issues with the documentation. For example, even today this documentation is incorrect: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj154121

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, there is indeed an issue with the documentation.

Try this as your request payload. This was provided to me by the person from Microsoft who wrote Windows Azure PowerShell Cmdlets:

```
<Disk xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure">
  <OS>Windows</OS>
  <Label>mydisk.vhd</Label>
  <MediaLink>https://vmdemostorage.blob.core.windows.net/uploads/mydisk.vhd</MediaLink>
  <Name>mydisk.vhd</Name>
</Disk>
```

I just tried using the XML above, and I can see an OS Disk in my subscription.

Comment: Hey Gaurav.

It looks like what i was doing, except the order is different. 
So i swapped the order in my code, and now it works.

Thank you :)